# Url's containing authentication secrets and app ID's

Tags: rest, uri

We received a request to create a REST api. I was a little confused in the example of provided by our client. As you can see below, they've identified the app_id and secret in the URL before the @. The remainder of the URI looks like what I would expect.

Is this valid? I thought maybe this is some weird cURL format I haven't seen before.

```
https://{application_id}:{api_secret}@api.example.com/entity/{entity_id}/ 
https://{application_id}:{api_secret}@api.example.com/entity/{entity_id}/entity_locations/{locations_id}/
```

Just seeing if anyone has seen this format before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URI is made up of [various parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax), one of them being the **authority** part, which can feature optional `username:password` element.

The full scheme is:

```
scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id
```

This way your REST api remains **stateless** [not relying on previous app states like storing stuff in session]. But I advice you not to explicitly go with the `username:password@stuff` route, but to rely on [Basic HTTP Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), so the credentials are sent encoded in Base64 at least.

---

EDIT: a brief note about BasicAuth now you're asking - things go like this:

- you make a request to `http://johndoe:12345@service/api/foo/bar`;
- are credentials good? Ok, you get a `200 OK` response with proper body;
- are they not? You get a `401 Unauthorized` response.

In the latter case, it's the **browser** [or any other program / script performing the request] that should prompt the user with the login popup.

Usually browsers ask you to cache credentials not to ask them every time, but this does not mean that they are not sent - it's just that every request to protected resources are featured with such header:

```
Authorization Basic base64encode(username:password)
```

Where `base64encode` is your custom way to encode the `username:password` string.

Comment: What would be the use case for that? I mean, that's not going to work for a GET request issued from your browser, or will it? If not, you can use that via cURL?

Comment: Yes it works, as long as that `username:password` is properly handed by the server, i.e. the credentials check are made on every request.

Comment: Ah, so if requested from the browser in that format, it will perform the basic HTTP auth without prompting you?